# Does jadeify download templates 1 by 1 on demand?

Tags: node.js, pug

I am thinking of using Jade templates on client side (with BackboneJS). Seems like I can use [`jadeify`](https://github.com/substack/node-jadeify). But was wondering, how does it work? Does it download each template 1 by 1 or compile all templates on serverside then serve a "compiled" templates file to the client? Looking at the source, it looks surprisingly short:

https://github.com/substack/node-jadeify/blob/master/jadeify.js

```
var views = require('jadeify/views'); ...

module.exports = function (file, vars, opts) {
    ...
    return $(jade.render(views[file], opts));
};
```

Line 1: can I even require a folder like that? Can I say views is now an array of scripts under that directory? That appear to be the case from Line 5, where `views[file]` is used.

---

But it calls `jade.render`. Won't it be more efficient to call `jade.compile` and cache it first? Or is it already cached somewhere?